# Xcode throws build error on M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild, apple-m1

We have an app which compiles properly on old Intel based MacBooks. However on M1 MacBook Pro, it's not compiling due to `arm64` compilation issue with latest iPhone simulators. It works till 13.7 simulators.

Based on few solutions on other posts, I tried to add `arm64` architecture in Excluded Architectures section also in Build Settings, but that throws a different error with Swift Package Manager, like
`Could not find module 'Viewer' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64, at: /Users/bappaditya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Aconex-dcwfxmeztacqqoewrptfilxusnyj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Viewer.framework/Modules/Viewer.swiftmodule`

The solution with opening with Rosetta works but some of the features like selecting photos from camera are broken due to this changes, so we can't accommodate this also.

We are seeking for a solution to compile our app on M1 without breaking any existing feature support.

[image: Xcode Build Settings]

Comment: You seem to be using a framework / Swift package called "Viewer", which has not been compiled for the Apple Silicon simulator. What framework is it? Can they provide an updated version with Apple Silicon support?

Comment: Let me check that too @Codo

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the build error opening XCode using Rosetta.

However, I have a problem running the app on simulator (white screen after splash). On device it's ok.

Comment: It won't help me with Rosetta, as some SPM does not work on Rosetta version